# Can I instruct the jar command to ignore .svn folders?

Tags: svn, web-applications, jar

My project is synced with svn. While deploying to the client, the .svn folders get included as a part of the build and the resulting war file size is doubled.

Is there a way I can specify the jar command to ignore .svn folders ?

This is how I use the command :

```
jar cvf ../MyProject.war .
```

Answer (score 2):

If I read

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/solaris/jar.html

correctly there is not. On the other hand you can achieve it quite easily using 'svn export' and a temporary directory. (Try 'svn help export' for intro to svn exporting). In short:

1. stand  in your project directory
2. do 'svn export *dirname*'
3. cd into *dirname*
4. run 'jar' in *dirname*
5. remove *dirname*

Later you'd like to automate this with a shell script or some such.

**Update:** I now see that the newer version of the docs gives more suggestions and points to strategies when choosing files:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/jar.html

Although if I were doing this, I'd still go for 'svn export' since it's a very straight-forward way of adding tree's.